# Is there a way to plot a dataset in "hidden" mode with Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

With Plotly one can interact with plots, clicking on the legend to enable/disable (or show/hide) particular datasets. Is there a way that I can plot a dataset that is "disabled" or "hidden" by default, requiring the user to click on it in order to see it?

In the example below, I have clicked on the Average line to disable it, but of course it is still there (just not shown). I would like to add several other datasets to this chart, but don't want to clutter the view by default.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using traces, you can use `visible="legendonly"` to hide it by default.